# socket.io getting error 404 when communicating between client and server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm making a small chat application using react, node and socket.io
I want to run the app at http://localhost:3002/chat-io/, but i'm getting the following error:

`GET http://localhost:3002/chat-io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N2YJ1pG 404 (Not Found)`

Server:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.path('/chat-io/socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');

const {
  addUser,
  removeUser,
  getUser,
  getUsersInRoom,
} = require('./users');

// Cors
app.use(cors());

// Serve static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use('/chat-io/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({ response: 'Server is up and running' });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join', ({ name, room }, callback) => {
    const { error, user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, name, room });

    if (error) return callback(error);

    socket.join(user.room);
    socket.emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name}, welcome to the room ${user.room}` });
    socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name} has joined` });

    io.to(user.room).emit('roomData', { room: user.room, users: getUsersInRoom(user.room) });

    return callback();
  });

  socket.on('sendMessage', (message, callback) => {
    const user = getUser(socket.id);

    io.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: user.name, text: message });
    io.to(user.room).emit('roomData', { room: user.room, users: getUsersInRoom(user.room) });

    return callback();
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);

    if (user) {
      io.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name} has left.` });
    }
  });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3002, () => {
  console.log(`Server has started on port ${process.env.PORT || 3002}`);
});
```

Client:

```
const Chat = ({ location }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [users, setUsers] = useState('');

  const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:3002';

  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);
    socket = io(ENDPOINT, { path: '/chat-io/socket.io' });
    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);

    socket.emit('join', { name, room }, (error) => {
      if (error) alert(error);
    });
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', (message) => {
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    });

    socket.on('roomData', ({ users }) => {
      setUsers(users);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.emit('disconnect');
      socket.off();
    };
  }, [messages]);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (message) socket.emit('sendMessage', message, () => setMessage(''));
  };
};
```

On the client there's also some jsx, but i don't think that's important.
I can get the code to run just fine on http://localhost:3002 but i want to run it on  http://localhost:3002/chat-io/

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your path be `io.path('/chat-io');`?

Comment: Still the same problem.